# Struts2: Specify max file size in upload validation message

Tags: validation, file-upload, struts2

I know how to override the default validation message

```
struts.messages.error.file.too.large=File uploaded is too large
```

And i know how to specify a custom file size for a particular action

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="allowedTypes">application/pdf</param>
    <param name="maximumSize">100000</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
```

Now my issue is, how I do override the default file size validation message to also include what the max file size actually is?

I want something like this where `${maximumSize}` is also in human readable format

```
struts.messages.error.file.too.large=File uploaded is too large: Max size is ${maximumSize}
```

Unfortunately the `${maximumSize}` does not work.  So i want to know how i can grab the size `${maximumSize}` parameter I specified and also put that in MB format in the validation message.

Comment: If you can then upgrade to latest S2 version where this is already implemented. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4389.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrM, if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can then upgrade to latest S2 version where this feature is already implemented. See jira issue [WW-4389](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4389) for more details.

Another option (if you cannot upgrade) is to extend `FileUploadInterceptor` class and override `acceptFile` method where this error message is being created.